# Trouble getting Selenum automated testing to auto-login using my profile

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using MS Edge browser (Version 109.0.1518.78) along with Selenium to do some automated UI testing with my corp environment.

Trouble is, the tests are always prompting challenging me to login.
Now here's the confusion: when i use Edge normally, the browser uses my profile settings to auto-authenticate me. However, when running the tests (via Visual Studio), an Edge browser instance is started WITHOUT my profile.

**First thing I tried:**

I have tried following various example without any success, such as [this one from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184163/edge-automation-with-selenium-credential-required-constantly). Using this example i added these 2 arguments like this:

[image]

This didn't do anything. So I'm wondering if maybe the arguments have changed? The edge driver documentation is worthless when it comes to this.

**Second thing I tried:**

I tried creating edge driver service with arguments of my edge driver path.
[image]

Unfortunately, i get a driver initialization error saying something about "msedge.exe".

**Summary**

The summarize, my problem is that my selenium tests are starting an edge browser instance without my default corp profile. therefore i am forced to manually login, which is what i want to avoid.

Note that occassionally things will work fine as expected. Then suddenly the next day it reverts to this default behavior again. I am no sure what is going on!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637211/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280195/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399027/7429447) discussion helps you?

Comment: About the first screenshot, you have to remove `\\Work` from the path